# Cant fit scikit-neuralnetwork classifier because of tuple index out of range

Tags: numpy, scikit-learn, theano

I am trying to get this [classifier](https://scikit-neuralnetwork.readthedocs.org/en/latest/guide_beginners.html#classification) working. It is a extension for scikit learn with dependencies to Theano.

My goal was to fit a neural network with a list of years and teach it to know if it is a leap year or not (later I would increase the range). But I run in an error if I want to test this example.

My code looks like this:

**leapyear.py**

```
import numpy as np
import calendar

from sknn.mlp import Classifier, Layer
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split

# create years in range
years = np.arange(1970, 2001)
pre_is_leap = []

# test if year is a leapyear
for x in years:
    pre_is_leap.append(calendar.isleap(x))

# convert true, false list to 0,1 list
is_leap = np.array(pre_is_leap, dtype=bool).astype(int)

# split
years_train, years_test, is_leap_train, is_leap_test = train_test_split(years, is_leap, test_size=0.33, random_state=42)

# test output
print(len(years_train))
print(len(is_leap_train))
print(years_train)
print(is_leap_train)

#neural network
nn = Classifier(
    layers=[
        Layer("Maxout", units=100, pieces=2),
        Layer("Softmax")],
    learning_rate=0.001,
    n_iter=25)

# fit

nn.fit(years_train, is_leap_train)
#nn.fit(np.array(years_train), np.array(is_leap_train))
```

requirements.txt

```
numpy==1.9.2
PyYAML==3.11
scikit-learn==0.16.1
scikit-neuralnetwork==0.3
scipy==0.16.0
Theano==0.7.0
```

my output with error:

```
20
20
[1986 1975 1983 1981 1992 1971 1972 1995 1973 1991 1996 1988 2000 1990 1977
 1980 1984 1998 1989 1976]
[0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1]
/home/devnull/master/scikit/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py:498: UserWarning: MinMaxScaler assumes floating point values as input, got int64
  "got %s" % (estimator, X.dtype))
/home/devnull/master/scikit/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sklearn/preprocessing/data.py:256: DeprecationWarning: Implicitly casting between incompatible kinds. In a future numpy release, this will raise an error. Use casting="unsafe" if this is intentional.
  X *= self.scale_
/home/devnull/master/scikit/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sklearn/preprocessing/data.py:257: DeprecationWarning: Implicitly casting between incompatible kinds. In a future numpy release, this will raise an error. Use casting="unsafe" if this is intentional.
  X += self.min_
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/devnull/master/scikit/leapyear.py", line 47, in <module>
    pipeline.fit(years_train, is_leap_train)
  File "/home/devnull/master/scikit/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sklearn/pipeline.py", line 141, in fit
    self.steps[-1][-1].fit(Xt, y, **fit_params)
  File "/home/devnull/master/scikit/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sknn/mlp.py", line 283, in fit
    return super(Classifier, self)._fit(X, yp)
  File "/home/devnull/master/scikit/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sknn/mlp.py", line 127, in _fit
    X, y = self._initialize(X, y)
  File "/home/devnull/master/scikit/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sknn/mlp.py", line 37, in _initialize
    self._create_specs(X, y)
  File "/home/devnull/master/scikit/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sknn/mlp.py", line 67, in _create_specs
    self.unit_counts = [numpy.product(X.shape[1:]) if self.is_convolution else X.shape[1]]
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

I looked into the sources of mlp.py, but I dont know how to fix it. What has to be changed that I can fit my network?

Update not question related:
I just wanted to add, that I need to convert the year to a binary representation, after this the neural network will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the classifier requires the data to be presented as a 2 dimensional numpy array, with the first axis being the samples and the second axis being the features.

In your case you have only one "feature" (the year) so you need to turn the years data into a Nx1 2D numpy array. This can be achieved by adding the following line just before the data split statement:

```
years = np.array([[year] for year in years])
```

Comment: `years = np.atleast_2d(years)` or `years = years[:, None]` should also work in a more vectorized manner.